# Как изменить свойство класса с помощью js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть `div` с классом `mystyle`. В классе есть свойство `margin` как его изменить с помощью обычного js или jquery?

```css
.mystyle, .mystyle ul {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="mystyle">
  <ul>
    <li>Пример</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 5):

Обычный JavaScript

```
document.getElementsByClassName('mystyle')[0].style.margin = "50px";
```

или так

```
document.getElementsByClassName('mystyle')[0].style= "margin: 50px";
```

jQuery

```
$('.mystyle').css('margin','50px');
```

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно поменять во всех элементах этого класса:

```
$('.mystyle').css('margin','10px')
```

Если прямо в стилях нужно поменять:

```js
$(function() {
  var ss = document.styleSheets[0];
  var rules = ss.cssRules || ss.rules;
  var h1Rule = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
    var rule = rules[i];
    if (/(^|,) *\.mystyle *(,|$)/i.test(rule.selectorText)) {
      h1Rule = rule;
      break;
    }
  }
  h1Rule.style.margin='10px'
  console.log(h1Rule.style.margin)

});
```

```css
.mystyle{
   margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="mystyle">Header</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getClassByName(className) {
  for (var ssNum in document.styleSheets)
    for (var ruleNum in document.styleSheets[ssNum].cssRules)
      if (document.styleSheets[ssNum].cssRules[ruleNum].selectorText)
        if (document.styleSheets[ssNum].cssRules[ruleNum].selectorText.indexOf(className) == 0)
          return document.styleSheets[ssNum].cssRules[ruleNum];
}
```

```css
.mystyle,
.mystyle ul {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="getClassByName('.mystyle').style.margin = '30px';">Изменить свойство класса</button>

<div class="mystyle">
  <ul>
    <li>Пример</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Невозможно переписывать CSS стиле с помощью JS. Лучше создай новый класс с нужными свойствами и добавляй его.

```
 .mystyle, .mystyle ul {
   margin: 0;
 }

 .mystyle.active {
   margin: 20px 0;
 }

 .mystyle.active ul {
   margin: 0 50px;
 }
```

JavaScript

```
 document.querySelector('.mystyle').classList.add('active');
```

jQuery

```
$('.mystyle').addClass('active');
```

Comment: Неправда. Возможно. Но jQuery в этом не помощник.