# Как закрыть элемент сайта от неавторизированных пользователей

Tags: javascript, php, html

У меня на странице есть кнопка, которая хранит две ссылки. Первая ссылка на тест (Text.html), а вторая на регистрацию (sign.html). Так вот, при нажатии на кнопку, система должна проверять зарегистрирован он или нет и в соответствии этого "отправляет" пользователя по одной из ссылок. Как это сделать либо в PHP либо в JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, наиболее подходящим будет вариант на php, и авторизованность пользователя можно быстро проверить и никаких задержек из-за загрузки скрипта не будет.

**index.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

//Код страницы до кнопок здесь

<?php if (!isset($_SESSION["USERNAME"])) { ?>
    <button id="clickMe" onclick="location.href='http://www.example.com/sign.html'">Регистрация</button>
<?php } else { ?>
    <button id="clickMe" onclick="location.href='http://www.example.com/Text.html'">Текст</button>
<?php } ?>

//Код страницы после кнопок здесь
```

**Замечание:** требуется сохранять имя пользователя в сессионных куках для работоспособности

Comment: Т.е мне на мой html сайт надо добавить ссылку на php документ и в нем прописать всё,что Вы написали? Или сайт из html сделать php?

Comment: @Onix, изменить расширение файла с `.html` на `.php`

Answer (score 0):

Если функционал не несет какой-то коммерческой тайны и вам нужно настроить отображение, то в данном случае css, js.

Изначально скрыть элемент css:

```
...html
<div id="private-container">
   <button></button>
</div>
html...
```

`{#private-container: display:none;}`

---

[Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633429/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-js) можете найти, как манипулировать с css при помощи js, jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю делается это не так. У кнопки обработчик всегда один соответственно ссылка тоже одна. Сервер получивший запрос от клиента должен определить статус сессии и ответить либо редиректом либо что у вас там заготовлено.